# Stripe manual/automatic capture

Tags: java, flutter, stripe-payments

Is there a way to capture the amount of payment after a predetermined time ?

I want that Stripe make the capture i created but only after 5 minutes from now.

```
/* the capture is a full capture, with this use case you cannot capture partially the amount */
paymentIntent.capture();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you use `capture_method: manual` when you create your PaymentIntent to authorize for up to 7 days. Then you use the [capture endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture) to actually capture the authorization. Take a look at [the docs on manual capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method).

Comment: But can i automate the authorization after 5 minutes from creation? I don't want ti call the endpoint from my server

Comment: No this isn't possible. You would have to use Webhooks or some other way to have your server capture the PaymentIntent 5 mins after authorization. You can only capture from your server.